# ODATA : Filter in parent and child table

Tags: odata

I am trying to get the result from odata using filter in header table and child table.

Following is the ODATA URL not working.

[ODATA Not working URL](https://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Products?$filter%20=%20ID%20eq%203%20and%20Supplier/State%20eq%20'WA'%20&$expand%20=%20Supplier)

Error i get is

```
Could not find a property named 'State' on type 'ODataDemo.Supplier'
```

If you check the working URL , you can see the State field .

If i remove the `and Supplier/State eq 'WA'` from above the url works fine. 
[image: Working]

Please guide.

Regards

Prat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Supplier/Address/State:

https://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Products?$filter%20=%20ID%20eq%203%20and%20Supplier/Address/State%20eq%20%27WA%27%20&$expand%20=%20Supplier

Comment: Yes this work. As this was an example for my case , but my actual case is not working.

Comment: Well, you were missing the Address part in the filter. It‘s Supplier/Address/State, not Supplier/State